# Class based views

Tags: django, url, slug

I'm experimenting with class based views as I've not worked with them yet. I'm also pretty new to Django. I'm having trouble correctly using slug or pk and setting up my URL's in my products app.

My Project level urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),
    path('checkout/', include('checkout.urls')),
]
```

urls.py(product app):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ItemDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='products'),
]
```

views.py(products app):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from home.models import Item


def products(request):
    context = {
        'items': Item.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "products/products.html", context)


class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "products/product.html"
```

I have tried adding `<slug>/` to the products url pattern but that doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I need to adjust my url's but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `path('<slug:slug>', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail')` does not work ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get at a 404.

Using the URLconf defined in beersub.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
accounts/
[name='home']
products/ <slug:slug> [name='product-detail']
checkout/
The current path, products/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Well it's normal it gives you a 404 if you don't give him any slug. The detail view expects something that let Django identifies the instance you want to obtain in your page. So the URL you write in your browser needs to look something like `products/my-slug` if you use a slug or `products/1` (or any other primary key) if you use an url like `path('<pk:int>', ...)`

Comment: I see. I think I've got it. Thanks for your reply!